# Problems with reading from file in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been having trouble with reading contents from a file whose path is provided by the user in a map reduce job using hadoop 1.1.2. The below code is what I've been trying to use, but when reading the content of the file, I always get null. I came across a few solutions here but none of them worked for me:

Main function:

```
    Job job = new Job (conf, "Find K-Nearest Neighbour");
    job.setJarByClass(Knn.class);
    DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("knnParamFile").toUri(), con);
```

Mapper class (Setup function):

```
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

    if (DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf) != null && DistributedCache.getCacheFiles(conf).length > 0)
    {

        String knnParams = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("./knnParamFile"));
         // rest of logic
     }
```

Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Try to use `job.getConfiguration()` in the `addCacheFile` method instead of `conf`. Modification of the `conf` may not affect job's configuration.

Comment: The job is declared in main and the addCacheFile that you are referring to is in the Mapper class. I don't know how to get the job declared in main to Mapper

Answer (score 0):

Please find a working code at

> http://bytepadding.com/big-data/map-reduce/map-side-joins-in-map-reduce/

```
please use  job.addCacheFile(inputPathDistributed.toUri());
```

to add files in the distributed cache

Comment: The job.addCacheFile(inputPathDistributed.toUri()); isn't an option with hadoop 1.1.2. The link you provided has code working with 2nd generation hadoop. In my case, I can't use second generation hadoop for research purposes